# populate images with firebase recycler adapter through databinding

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, picasso, android-glide, android-databinding, firebaseui

I am populating a firebase data with firebase recycler adapter through databinding and want to populate images with the data either from Picasso or Glide, but unable to do. So can any one help me what to write and where to write the code of either Picasso or Glide.

```
public class ShopByCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
Firebase mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://abc.firebaseio.com/").child("subCategories");

public ShopByCategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SubCategories, ViewHolder>(SubCategories.class, R.layout.fragment_shop_by_category,
            ViewHolder.class, mFirebaseRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, SubCategories subCategories, int i) {


            FragmentShopByCategoryBinding binding = viewHolder.getBinding();
            binding.setSubCategories(subCategories);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    return rootView;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public FragmentShopByCategoryBinding binding;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
    }
    public FragmentShopByCategoryBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    adapter.cleanup();
}
```

}

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="SubCategories"
        type="com.abc.www.shopping.model.SubCategories"/>
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
            android:id="@+id/sub_category_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@{SubCategories.image}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
            android:text="@{SubCategories.title}"
            android:id="@+id/sub_category_title"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSubCategoryTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

```
public class SubCategories extends BaseObservable {

private String title;
private String image;

public SubCategories() {
    // empty constructor
}

public SubCategories(String title, String image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

}

Comment: same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356241/image-are-not-getting-loaded-using-firebaserecycleradapter

Answer (score 1):

I have made something similar to what you need. I'll share my code and do a little explanation.

I have a class that returns the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter like this:

```
public RecyclerView.Adapter postAdapter(String userKey, final Context context, MyClickListener clickListener) {
    Query userPostRef = postRef.child(userKey);
    myClickListener = clickListener;

    return new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostModel, DataObjectHolder>(PostModel.class, R.layout.stream_layout, DataObjectHolder.class, userPostRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder dataviewHolder, final PostModel postModel, int position) {
            StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            mStorageRef.child("uploaded_captures/" + postModel.getImageFilename() + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            dataviewHolder.setImage(uri.toString(), context);
                            dataviewHolder.setComment(postModel.getPostComment());
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Log.e("FirebaseRecyclerAdapter", exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

and a ViewHolder that loads the image into the ImageView used by the layout:

```
private static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    View mView;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    void setImage(final String imageURL, final Context context) {
        final ImageView postImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        }
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .fit().centerCrop().into(postImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(imageURL)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                        .fit().centerCrop().into(postImage);
            }
        });
    }

    void setComment(String text) {
        TextView comment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        comment.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }
}
```

On Picasso I'm using the NerworkPolicy.OFFLINE to check if the image is on the disk cache before trying to get it from the network. It's not perfect and I'm still having some issues with the delay of the images once the ViewHolder it's been recycled but I think it's a start for you to go on.

Answer (score 0):

In my ViewHolder I do this by:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(chat.getImageUrl())
     .into(imageView);
```

I haven't tried using [data binding](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) for this yet, but the code is simple enough.

Comment: I have tried with viewholder but it gives an error databinding doesnot exists