# image are not getting loaded using firebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, android-glide

**everything is working fine but images are not getting loaded**

[this image from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzdyn.png)

[this image display the value log of image-getimgUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TduPM.png)

[this image frome firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzOcU.png)

**the problem her is the value of image and getimgUrl = NULL**

public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext()));


    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,mViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, mViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row,mViewHolder.class,mRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(mViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setImage(getBaseContext(),model.getImgUrl());

            Log.e("getImgUrl", "value : "+model.getImgUrl());
            Log.e("getTitle", "value : "+model.getTitle());
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public static class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mview;

    public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        mview = itemView;

    }


    public void setTitle(String title){

        TextView postTitle = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.text_row);
        postTitle.setText(title);

        Log.e("title", "value : "+title);
        }
    public void setImage(Context ctx,String image){

        ImageView postImage = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.image_row);

        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(postImage);

        Log.e("image", "value : "+image);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What does `RÉPONDRE` mean?

Comment: nothing written mistake

Comment: By the way, you can edit your question.

Comment: can't edit it im new on stackoverflow :D

Comment: You can edit by using the edit link under your question. Or click on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47356241/edit).

Comment: that's ok so can you help me to solve that problem

Comment: The `TextView` is populated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is wrong. Try this:

```
public final class Model {
    // Excluding these fields because proguard can make them public
    @Exclude private String mTitle;
    @Exclude private String mImage;

    public Model() {
        // Needed for Firebase
    }

    @Keep
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    @Keep
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    @Keep
    public String getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    // The "image" part of `setImage` needs to match what it's called in your database.
    // Or you could use `@PropertyName("nameInTheDatabase")`
    @Keep
    public void setImage(String image) {
        mImage = image;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Model model = (Model) o;

        return (mTitle == null ? model.mTitle == null : mTitle.equals(model.mTitle))
                && (mImage == null ? model.mImage == null : mImage.equals(model.mImage));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = mTitle == null ? 0 : mTitle.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (mImage == null ? 0 : mImage.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "mTitle='" + mTitle + '\'' +
                ", mImage='" + mImage + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!

Comment: This helped me as well... I feel like firebase needs to make it more that when setting the name of the node in the db it needs to be the same as the name in the POJO class... thanks a lot though... took me a day and a half to solve this because no one else's solution provided a comment like yours.

Answer (score 0):

use Glide 3.7.0 version Library instead of Picasso and use `itemView` `context` intead of `ApplicationContext`

```
public void setImage(String imageUrl){

    ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCardRow);

    Glide.with(mview.getContext).load(imageUrl).into(post_image);
}
```